# APEX - 21.1 - Calculate the ageing of a task

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have columns Status, Updated_Time, Ageing
When status is marked as WIP, I have below triggger to update the "Updated_Time" column with PST systime

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIG01
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TASKS
  REFERENCING FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.STATUS='WIP')
  BEGIN
  IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
    :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'PDT' );
   END IF;
END;
```

I'm planning to insert one more line to the trigger to calculate the ageing. It seems to be working via SQL command but from the interactive grid. Any suggestions on how to calculate the ageing of a task.

```
:NEW.AGEING := ROUND((CAST(NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'PDT') as DATE)- CAST(:NEW.UPDATED_DATE as DATE))*1440,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle or relational database in general, insert/update(DMLs) needed to be completed as part of single transaction and requires you to perform commit or rollback.
My guess here(as you have not shared specific details about how IG is programmed) is that it does not get committed and timed out.

My suggestion is to get either of this to solve the problem :

1. Use pragma within your trigger Or
2. Use Apex dynamic action to calculate Date and Aging